# Как обработать ключ, являющийся одновременно и первичным, и внешним в Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

Есть таблица `Applicant`, в которой первичный ключ - `id` - автоинкрементный:

```
applicant (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

И таблица `Deal`, в которой первичный ключ - `applicant_id` - это внешний ключ, ссылающийся на `Applicant(id)`:

```
deal (
    applicant_id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(applicant_id),
    FOREING KEY(applicant_id) REEFERENCES applicant(id)
);
```

так реализована связь 1 к 1.

Как эту связь правильно описать в модели Deal в Spring-проекте? Как должна выглядеть модель Deal?

Comment: Можно открыть документацию и попробовать самому для начала)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "applicant")
public class Applicant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "applicant",
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Deal deal;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "deal")
public class Deal {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "applicant_id")
    private Long applicantId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Applicant applicant;
}
```

`@MapsId` указывает Hibernate использовать столбец `applicant_id` таблицы `deal` в качестве первичного и внешнего ключа.

Также обратите внимание, что столбец `id` таблицы `applicant` не использует `@GeneratedValue`.

Атрибут `mappedBy` в классе `Applicant`, поскольку внешний ключ теперь присутствует в таблице `deal`.